# compare two files

Tags: python, text-processing

I have two files in this format

```
file1= filename val1 val2
file2= filename val3 val4
```

I want to compare filenames and if they have the same names , i want to get a third file like this-

```
filename val1 val2 val3 val4
```

I am picking a filename from `file1` and going across `file2` to see if i get it. Then seeking pointer back to the top of `file2` for the next filename..is there a more efficient way of doing it?

Comment: You might want to clarify your question and show the code you are using.

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like what you're looking for is the standard `join` command (not Python, but a standard Unix shell utility). Here's a snip from the manual page on a system (that seems to have more detail than the Linux [man page for join](http://linux.die.net/man/1/join)):

```
        join phonedir names

        If the phonedir file contains the following names:

        Adams A.        555-6235
        Dickerson B.    555-1842
        Erwin G.        555-1234
        Jackson J.      555-0256
        Lewis B.        555-3237
        Norwood M.      555-5341
        Smartt D.       555-1540
        Wright M.       555-1234
        Xandy G.        555-5015

        and the names file contains these names and department numbers:

        Erwin           Dept. 389
        Frost           Dept. 217
        Nicholson       Dept. 311
        Norwood         Dept. 454
        Wright          Dept. 520
        Xandy           Dept. 999

        the join command displays:

        Erwin G.        555-1234        Dept. 389
        Norwood M.      555-5341        Dept. 454
        Wright M.       555-1234        Dept. 520
        Xandy G.        555-5015        Dept. 999
```

Comment: thanks ! Unfortunately i am getting an extra new line ..so the final result i am getting is  filename val1 val2 (on new line) val3 val4 . I want it to be like how you showed it to be - without the newline after file1. I am using join file1 file2 > outputfile

Comment: @Illusionist: It's *possible* that is related to the line endings. Are your file perhaps CRLF terminated (DOS style)?

Comment: Then you'll definitely want to convert those files to LF only, because the `join` command probably doesn't quite know how to deal with the CRLF files (it will treat the CR as part of the line, not knowing that it's part of the CRLF).

Answer (score 2):

create a dict `file2[filename] = (val3, val4)`. you can create this once, then lookup time for a given filename you get from file1 takes constant time (ie is more or less independent on the size of file2)